# Unknown Data Structure?

Tags: java, data-structures

I had a question about whether or not Java has its own data structure for what I am looking for. **It is something like a combination of an array, linked list and a tree.**

If it is not in Java, but exists already as a concept in computer science/other languages, that is also an acceptable answer so I can research it more and find out how to implement it myself.

Here is a picture to better illustrate what I am looking for. Excuse the lack of professionalism; I made it as best as I could:

[image]

I am looking for something that starts with several indexed starting elements, that eventually link to other elements and end in a convergence of sorts (one final element). In the end, each index has its corresponding starting element, which is linked all the way to the final converged element.

It should be the case that asking for `unknownStructure[i]` or something should grab an object that is a representation of the i<sup>th</sup> starting element linked all the way to the final converged element. (This thing to be grabbed is outlined in various bright colors in the picture).

Comment: This is a Tree with all its leaf nodes references stored in an associated List.  It would be easy to create by updating the associated list on any Tree function that changes the state of the leaf nodes ( re-balancing etc. ).  Unfortunately Java notoriously doesn't have any Graph collections for some reason.

Comment: The image resembles a part of an [artificial neural network](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) (ANN). What would you use this for?

Comment: I am using this to handle equation parsing for error propagation calculation. I don't believe I have enough space in a comment to explain fully, but I have a need to incrementally break down an equation into parts that all fit together dependently. You can read more about the concept in experimental physics/chemistry at this very simple link here:
http://lectureonline.cl.msu.edu/~mmp/labs/error/e2.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "name" for this that I know of, but an array of linked list nodes would work quite well for this.

Traditionally linked lists are separate and simply a row of items pointing to the next. However, there is no reason why certain linked list nodes cannot point to the same child node. After all, trees and linked lists are essentially created the same way in Java.

The only foreseeable problem would be if you want to traverse this "tree" back to the starting node in the array. (Which could still be achieved with multiple parent support.)

To implement your linked-list array, simply created a `Node` class as for a linked list and then created an array of these elements:

```
Node[] myTreeArray = new Node[];
```

Then simply fill this array with your "base" nodes and link them to their appropriate children (eventually leading the the "end" node, which has a child of `null`)

Comment: I think this is the most intuitive and simple approach to this problem. However, can I have it so that two different nodes can have the same child node in Java? If so, I think this is pretty perfect for my needs.

Comment: @Utagai Yes you can! Simply have both point to the same child node! (In fact, you would need this to happen for a directed graph to work as well.)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are looking for a **directed Graph** data structure.
You may need to use a list of graphs if needed.

See this [page](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Graph) for algorithms and [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Adirectedgraphdatastructure.htm) for implementation.

Comment: I supposed this could be seen as a directed graph (though really anything is a graph if you try hard enough.) Unusual to have so many starting nodes though.

Comment: I was considering a directed graph and figured that this does fit under that category, but it just didn't seem specific enough. However, the implementation seems a bit too complex and thorough for my needs. I think I'll skip the extra stuff. Looking into using nodes as suggested by River.

Comment: There are nodes and ages in graphs when linked-list has only nodes. The graphs are not that complicated once you complete first implementation. You may see short [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfCo5A4HGKc) that will help to understand theory and its implementation.

Comment: @MaxZoom edges might be something OP doesn't even need. And if he/she does, you can always implement them in a linked-list fairly easily as well. Always better to roll your own for simple data-structures in my opinion.

Comment: River is correct. I have absolutely no need for edges. River suggested using nodes and adding in child relationships manually. This is actually perfect since this is about all I need to do (after storing the initial nodes in an array). Since I can do everything I need with a Java API class, why incorporate someone else's implementation of a directed graph?